# Django: PhoneNumberField Not getting Installed

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I intalled Phonenumber package via pip and mentioned in my installed apps.
As well as imported the same as mentioned in documentation to my models.py
Even re-checked at the stack answers most of the people did the installation and imported file, but why mine is not working can anyone help

```
pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'rk003.apps.Rk003Config',
]
```

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# Create your models here.


class Agent(models.Model):
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prop_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    agency_address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    agency_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agency_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    contact_nu = models.PhoneNumberField()
```

Error is as follows

```
 File "/Users/rishipalsingh/Projects/notes/mdndjango/rk002/rk003/models.py", line 13, in Agent
    contact_nu = models.PhoneNumberField()
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'PhoneNumberField'
```

Comment: `contact_nu = PhoneNumberField()`...

Answer (score 3):

Its suppose to be **contact_nu = PhoneNumberField()**.
You are not importing the PhoneNumberField() field from models. You have already imported it from phonenumber_field.modelfields